# Unknown command error - SQL+/Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am doing a query for a class where I need to select pet owner names based on whether or not they own a Chihuahua.

I have to use two tables, PetOwner and Pet. PetOwner has an owner number (ownerNo), owner name (oLName, oFName), and Pet has owner number and petType. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
SELECT 
    PetOwner.oFName, 
    PetOwner.oLName
FROM 
    PetOwner, 
    Pet
WHERE 
    PetOwner.ownerNo = (SELECT 
                            Pet.ownerNumber 
                        FROM 
                            Pet 
                        WHERE 
                            Pet.petType = 'Chihuahua'
                        );
```

The error says "unknown command beginning "Pet.petTyp..." - rest of line ignored." I know the issue is in the WHERE clause, but I can't seem to tweak it to where it will work, and I am sure the answer is obvious.

I just need a second set of eyes to look it over.

How can i do this ?

Comment: what kind of unknown error like error no: spxxxxx

Comment: I think in sub query you haven't written top clause & checking that result with = operator. Does it make difference?

Comment: provide alias to your child query table. have a look my answer for detail information.

Comment: If you are using SQL*Plus (which is Oracle's command line client) why did you tag this with `mysql`. Which DBMS are you really using?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your query:

```
SELECT PetOwner.oFName, PetOwner.oLName
FROM PetOwner, Pet
```

You have mentioned the table 'Pet' here. Table 'Pet' shouldn't be mentioned here, as you're selecting the oFName and oLName from the table 'PetOwner', not 'Pet'.

A simple join query will give you exactly what you want. No need to use subquery in the above mentioned way. You need to join Pet table with PetOwner table, based on PetOwner.ownerNo = Pet.ownerNumber, under the condition that Pet.petType is 'Chihuahua'.

So the completed query is:

```
SELECT po.oFname, po.oLName
FROM PetOwner as po
JOIN Pet as p
ON po.ownerNo = p.ownerNumber
WHERE p.petType = 'Chihuahua'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT oFName, oLName
 FROM PetOwner
 WHERE ownerNo = (SELECT ownerNumber FROM Pet WHERE petType = 'Chihuahua');
```

Comment: Review: Some explanation what was wrong would be appreciated. I might understand but it's not what we want that OP just copy & paste your code. The idea is that OP should understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following query worked for me:

```
SELECT ownername
FROM PetOwner
WHERE PetOwner.ownerNo = (SELECT Pet.ownerNo FROM Pet WHERE Pet.petType = 'Chihuahua');
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is confusing sql for which Pet to select parent one or child one. Provide alias for child table in your sub query as mentioned below :

```
SELECT 
    PetOwner.oFName, 
    PetOwner.oLName
FROM 
    PetOwner, 
    Pet
WHERE 
    PetOwner.ownerNo = (SELECT 
                            p.ownerNumber 
                        FROM 
                            Pet p
                        WHERE 
                            p.petType = 'Chihuahua'
                        );
```